# sles 9 not recognising hard disks

Tags: sles

Trying to install sles 9 onto one of the hard disks on a Fujitsu PRIMERGY rx200 s6 server. However seem to be encountering a problem in that sles does not seem to recognise that there are hard disks available to use. 
Tried installing off both cd and network and this problem is affecting all rx200 servers we own (6 different servers).

Could this be sles requiring drivers for the disk manger?

Look forward to any help.

Answer (score 1):

SLES9 is quite old. Note that its EOL was in August 2011. The latest version was SP4. Which SP version is yours?

Your server has propably a newer raid-controller. Try to boot with a rescue-CD SLES11 SP1 and check with `lsmod` which raid-driver is loaded. Try to find the source code for it and compile it on another machine. Then put it into your initrd.

Comment: I checked the fujitsu site about your server. You have some kind of LSI controller there (lspci -v on SLES11SP1 should show you details). You might be lucky on the LSI-webpage.